# Token for other spaces

Tags: slack-api

I read the documentation, and I still have a doubt. I know where I can get the auth token for the current workspace that I have.

My pain is, how can I get the access token when I publish this bot? How can I do it programmatically?

I know that under `OAuth & Permissions`, it is possible to set the `Redirect URLs`.

If I understood correctly, this URL would receive an HTTP GET call with a `code` query param.

If my assumptions are correct, how can I test that? Only after I hit the "publish" button? Right now, even if I "reinstall" my app, my callback is not invoked.

Thank you

Comment: No, you can use the Auth process to install your Slack app once you enabled your app for distribution. You do not need to publish it for that.

Comment: thank you for the help. Will I have to use the same auth token to all teams?

Comment: my question is basically, what should I do regarding multiple teams/companies? do I need one token per team?

Comment: You need to submit your app to slack app directory, this is the only for your app to be accessible by multiple work-spaces.

Comment: No, how it works is: when a team installs your app if will always create a new token for that team. You app must collect and store that token in order to use the API for that team.

Comment: good, and how do I collect it? it is by callback?

Comment: https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2#obtaining

Comment: Hello Erik, thank you for the patient and your help. if I understood correctly, I need to provide an URL that requests authorization with a callback URL. what if the user installs my app from the Slack app "store". Is there a way to configure my URL with a callback?

Comment: no worries. happy to help. yes, you configure your callback on the management page of your Slack app. It must point to the route of your app that handles the OAuth flow

Comment: Here is an example how that works in Python: https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/auth.html#multiple-workspace-install

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I was able to integrate now with the install option. What was killing me was to know how would the user get the URL with my data. I was able to make it work now.